# push notification in windows phone 8

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, cloud

Hello friends i am following this [Push notification link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-wp8/) and able to implement it . it is working but i tried to change the CurrentChannel name from MyPushChannel to Channeltest then it is not able to create new channel and throwing exception of invalidOperation type will you guys please explain me why it is happening here is the code..

```
private void AcquirePushChannel()
    {
        CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("Channeltest");


        if (CurrentChannel == null)
        {
            CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("Channeltest");
            CurrentChannel.Open(); // exception comming here
            CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone, you have a restriction per application of one push channel. If you want to change the name, uninstall the app from the device/emulator and make the deployment again. It should work.

Comment: josue have you used notification hub for windows phone 8 ..i needed some help

Comment: Hi Tanuj, sorry but i don't had use notification hub :(